# How to use cards with Bootstrap 4 on multiple line with fixed size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**Objectives:**

- All cards have same height (128px)  and width (128px)
- If there are lot of cards
  and the screen isn't wide enough, show cards on the second line.

I using Bootstrap 4, and currently, my cards are only on one line. I read the documentation and I tried a lot of code. Currently, I don't understand why my cards are too small and not respect the size of 128px. 
The result is same a grid system responsive.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello</title>
  </head>

  <body class="text-center">
      <div id='main-content' class="card-deck" style="margin: 50px 0 0 0">

          <div class="card mb-4" style="max-width: 128px; max-width: 128px">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/"><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img-top"></a>
          </div><span></span>
          
          <div class="card mb-4" style="width: 128px; height: 128px">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com"><img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img-top"></a>
          </div><span></span>
          
          <div class="card mb-4" style="width: 128px; height: 128px">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com"><img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img-top"></a>
          </div><span></span>
          
          <div class="card mb-4" style="width: 128px; height: 128px">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com"><img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img-top"></a>
          </div><span></span>
          
          <div class="card mb-4" style="width: 128px; height: 128px">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com"><img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img-top"></a>
          </div><span></span>
          
          <div class="card mb-4" style="width: 128px; height: 128px">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com"><img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img-top"></a>
          </div><span></span>
          
          <div class="card mb-4" style="width: 128px; height: 128px">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com"><img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img-top"></a>
          </div><span></span>
          
          <div class="card mb-4" style="width: 128px; height: 128px">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com"><img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img-top"></a>
          </div><span></span>
          
          
          </div>


    

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: pull them out of the `.card-deck` class. this class will overwrite your inline styles because the the `card-deck` class nests `card-deck > card` and your inline style is only applied to `card`

Comment: although I would probably use col classes to control sizes so that the responsive break points get respected.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take your cards out of the `card-deck` and put them into a `row`. And if you want to center the whole thing horizontally, add the `justify-content-center` class to the row like so (click the "run code button" and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<style>
    .card-custom {
        max-width: 128px;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center">
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that I've also added the classes `mx-2 mb-3` for spacing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations, it's works :)

Comment: Glad to hear that! :-)

Comment: Last question: I using `justify-content-center` but the last line is "center" too so it's ugly. So, i tried without `justify-content-center` but how to center container ?

Comment: Well, there aren't many options in the case where you want them to be left-aligned and at the same time have the entire thing centered. That's because the max width of the individual items is limited here. There's only one option I can think of right now but that would be quite a setup because you'd have to have different classes for each breakpoint and I'm not 100% sure it would work. (needs to be tested)

Comment: But this is a different question and per SO rules we are not allowed to ask/answer multiple questions in one. So, feel free to post that as a new question.